Having a very basic probem with PIXI.js, unable to render a sprite on the screen
Apparently I am overlooking something very basic about pixi. I am trying to render a single sprite on the scene
I am using the asset loader to load in a texture, create a sprite, and render it to the screen. i am receiving no errors but the canvas just stays blank. i should mention that im using webpack. here's my code:
index.js

    import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
    import { roomSceneManifest } from './image_imports.js'

    async function loadAssets (){
      const app = new PIXI.Application()
      await app.init({ width: 800, height: 600 });
      document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);
    
      PIXI.Assets.init({manifest: roomSceneManifest})
    
      const assets = await PIXI.Assets.loadBundle('png');
      console.log(assets)
      const bg = PIXI.Sprite.from(assets.BackgroundImg);
      console.log(bg)
      bg.anchor.set(0.5);
      bg.x = app.screen.width / 2;
      bg.y = app.screen.height / 2;
      app.stage.addChild(bg);
    }

    loadAssets()




    ./image_imports.js

    export const roomSceneManifest =  {
       "bundles":[
          {
             "name":"png",
             "assets":[
                {
                   "alias":"BackgroundImg",
                   "src":BackgroundImg
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }

